# UITabBarController with portrait / landscape views

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, landscape

I have a subclass of UITabBarController which i am using so that i can rotate to use my app in landscape too.

How would i go about rotating my UI and getting each view controller to use a landscape view xib?

I have always just written apps before where returning YES for shouldAutorotate... handles it automatically for me... this isn't the case here now, as i'm using a custom view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to subclass UITabBarController to get the autorotation behavior. Instead what you should do is have ALL the UIViewControllers that appear in your UITabBarController return YES for shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:. If even one of them does not, the UITabBarController will not autorotate.

As for the custom view, it is associated with a UIViewController, right? If so, then if your custom view implements layoutSubviews using the current view bounds to lay out all the subviews, then it should autorotate correctly as well.

Comment: I tried setting all of my views to return YES, but it didnt seem to affect the auto rotation... what is layoutSubviews?

Comment: Just to clarify, did you set the views to return YES, or their view controllers? The views won't get asked, only the view controllers will.

Comment: I set the view controllers to return YES. How would i use layoutSubviews to lay out the subviews, using a xib? Thanks